# How set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for my application

Tags: android, android-ndk

there. How do I set the path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib to vendor` .so libraries so that my so library can use libraries from there? Now I get the following error

```
 dlopen failed: library "libc++.so" not found
```

Do I need to put some paths or flags in `build.gradle` for the `ndk` config? thanks

Comment: How are you building your library exactly? `libc++_shared.so` should automatically be bundled with your app if you build with gradle and have selected `c++_shared` as your STL implementation. There should be no need for you to package or load it yourself, or to specify any paths to it.

Comment: @Michael these .so files are copied from `jniLibs.srcDirs`. Another developer runs them as is with the path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib` without building the `apk`, apparently this path refers to all the necessary `.so` files from vendor. I can't pass the `.so` path 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' at startup and it considers its `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' the current directory